# How do I completely clear Symfony's cache, including templates?

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I just updated a template file in a Symfony 2 project. The HTML output of the page didn't change, so I removed all the files in `app/cache`. I hard reloaded the page, but the HTML still hadn't changed. I then ran `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` just in case cache files were saved somewhere outside the cache folder. Still didn't work.

I have confirmed that the template file on the production server does *not* match the output HTML. I have confirmed that all the files in the config folder was removed. It is *not* my browser caching the HTML, because the data in the HTML output changes.

If I remove the view file, I get a 500 Internal Server Error, and if I restore the file, the same old template is displayed by Symfony again.

***How is this possible?*** Is Symfony saving cached templates somewhere outside the cache folder, then *not* clearing them when I request a cleared cache? Please help me understand this.

Comment: When you deleted app/cache/*, did you do it as root? i.e. >sudo rm -fr app/cache/*

Comment: @EddieJaoude: Yes, but what does it matter? As I said, I have confirmed that it is empty.

Comment: Just double checking, as it is an issue I have seen many times before, where it was not removed properly.

Comment: Yes, check APC (you can clear it by restarting your webserver). Also, do you use apache's mod_expires? If so, check `ExpiresByType text/html`

Comment: What's about local browser cache?

Comment: @Pazi: did you even read the question?

Comment: Not word for word :-P missed the hard before reloaded. Have you a proxy configured?